# Access a method after an event assigned on a callback (WebGIS app)

Tags: javascript

## Background

I am working on a WebGIS application using JavaScript and ArcGIS JS API. I am new with js, so please bear with me.

While learning and developing with js, I am trying to follow some rules, such as Asynchronous Module Definition (which ArcGIS JS API encourages), Revealing Module Pattern, and the Standard Style. Certainly, I still fail at following them correctly.

This code is built on top of this responsive template: github.com/Esri/bootstrap-map-js.

## Objective

This app consumes some ArcGIS REST services (MapServer). Assume that I don't have any control over them (I have access to server, but that is another thing that I know nothing about).

One of the functionalities is to filter a certain layer (Feature Layer with Polyline geometry), according to a selection that the user does using check boxes. When a check box is checked, only some parts of the layer should be visible. If multiple checks are done, the visible parts of the layer must have
different colors.

## Code

I set up an example of this application using one of the example ArcGIS services. It is available in this repo: https://github.com/iled/fiddle
(sorry, I failed at making a jsfiddle out of it)

Below I make a brief description of the relevant parts of the code (file *app/js/map.js*)

**Add the layer**

When the map is added, all layers on the service are automatically loaded and placed in a tree with checkboxes.

```
restUrl = "http://sampleserver5.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Water_Network/MapServer"
var mapServiceLayer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(restUrl, opt)
map.addLayer(mapServiceLayer)
```

**Check boxes**

These check boxes are built with all possible values, of a given attribute (`facilityid`), within one of the layers (*MidScale/Water Mains - Block View* -- it is the last one inside *layer1*), so they should filter that layer.

Here is how those values are fetched.

```
var queryOperators = function (mapServiceLayer) {
  var queryTask = new QueryTask("http://sampleserver5.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Water_Network/MapServer/23")
  var query = new Query()
  var mps = mapServiceLayer
  query.returnGeometry = false
  query.outFields = ["facilityid"]
    // toy query to fetch all records
  query.where = "1 = 1"
  query.returnDistinctValue = true
  query.orderByFields = ["facilityid ASC"]
  queryTask.execute(query, addOperatorsList)
}
```

The list of check boxes is then built by the callback method.

```
var addOperatorsList = function (operatorsFeatureSet) {
  var operatorsCount = operatorsFeatureSet.features.length
  var operatorsNames = []
  var operatorsList = []
  var operatorsDiv = dom.byId("operatorList")
  var line = "<input  id='operatorCheckBox_'"
  for (var i = 0; i < operatorsCount; i++) {
    operatorsNames.push(operatorsFeatureSet.features[i].attributes["facilityid"])

    domConstruct.create("p", {
      id: "operatorCheckBox_" + i,
      style: "font-size:10px"
    }, operatorsDiv)

    domConstruct.create("label", {
      for: "opbox_" + i,
      innerHTML: operatorsNames[i]
    }, "operatorCheckBox_" + i)

    var cbox = new CheckBox({
      id: "opbox_" + i,
      value: operatorsFeatureSet.features[i].attributes["facilityid"],
      checked: false,
      onChange: function (evt) {
        console.log('value:', this.value)
        querySegments(this.value)
      }
    })
    cbox.placeAt("operatorCheckBox_" + i, "first")
  }
}
```

**Filter the layer**

Here is where one of the problems is located, the method `setLayerDefinitions` fails with the message `Uncaught TypeError: this.setLayerDefinitions is not a function`. I know that this is not supposed to work, here, `this` is just a placeholder for whatever I've got to put there.

```
var querySegments = function (operator_id) {
    // build the query
    var queryStatement = "facilityid = " + operator_id
    var layerDefinitions = [queryStatement]
    console.log(layerDefinitions)
    this.setLayerDefinitions(layerDefinitions)
}
```

This function is called when an event is fired up, which connection was defined on a callback function. How to reach the target layer from here is kind of obscure to me...

## Example

If a user checks the box with the number `128608`, the result should look like this (taken from ArcGIS webmap viewer).

[image: Example of the polyline with <code>facilityid = 128608</code>.]

## Problems/Questions

1. After getting the data from the toggled check box, I can't reach the layer in order to call the method that would filter it.
2. How to hide/remove *layer0* and *layer1* (labels and check boxes) from the layers list? More generally, how to format this list?
3. After selection and filtering, how to give different colors to each *filtered polyline*?

Please, let me know if I can improve the question in any way.

I thought about posting this on other StackExchange sites (SO, gis), but I decided to post it here because it involves a larger code review; I'll also appreciate if someone explains that I should do otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. From the code lines you posted above, you could replace `this.setLayerDefinitions()` to `mapServiceLayer.setLayerDefinitions()`. Othewise, you'll have to pass the layer you queried, from your function `queryOperators()` to `querySegments()` in this way :

```js
var queryOperators = function(mapServiceLayer) {
  ...
  queryTask.execute(query, function(res) {
    addOperatorsList(res, mps);
  });
};
var cbox = new CheckBox({
  ...
  onChange: function(evt) {
    querySegments(this.value, layer);
  }
});
var querySegments = function(operator_id, layer) {
  ...
  layer.setLayerDefinitions(layerDefinitions);
};
```

2. I'm not sure what you want to do, but I guess the first example from this dojo example will suit your need https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/store/Observable.html#dojo-store-observable
3. apply a new Symbol to your *selected polyline*, then add that Graphic to the map.

```js
var cbox = new CheckBox({
    ...
    onChange: function(evt) {
      ...
      var polyline = operatorsFeatureSet.features[i];
      showPolyline(polyline);
    }
  });
```

And outside addOperatorsList function :

```
var showPolyline = function(polyline) {
  function randomColor() {
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 0);
  }
  var symbol = new SimpleLineSymbol();
  symbol.setColor(new Color([randomColor(), randomColor(), randomColor(), 1]));
  var graphic = new Graphic(polyline, symbol);
  map.graphics.add(graphic);
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! This was some time ago and I'm no longer working on that project. At the time, I guess I finally got it working in a similar fashion to what you described, so I'm accepting your answer (I'm sorry I forgot to come here post my own findings).

Comment: hey ! thanks for your feedback, much appreciated :) glad you finally managed to get it working in a way or another. cheers